# Embed external framework into home-made private framework in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios-frameworks

I built a framework using Xcode 6 and Swift, and my framework uses [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) as a dependency - added through [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage). I archived my framework and created a build for both simulator and iOS devices using `lipo`, and when trying to use my framework into an empty app, I get a crash at runtime:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON
Referenced from: /Users/hd/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/324FD1CD-4A06-459B-AE6D-318197B5697E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/555871BB-7AA1-4AED-90CE-EE0A628A794F/CollaborativeTodo.app/Frameworks/XXXXX.framework/XXXXX
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Users/hd/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/324FD1CD-4A06-459B-AE6D-318197B5697E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/555871BB-7AA1-4AED-90CE-EE0A628A794F/CollaborativeTodo.app/Frameworks/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

Here's what my arborescence look like -- my framework name is deliberately blurred:

[image: Project arborescence]

General tab:

[image: General]

Build Phases:
[image: Build Phases]

It works if I include SwiftyJSON using Carthage in my project, but I don't want the user to be forced to include third-party libraries. **How to embed SwiftyJSON into my framework and tell Xcode to use the embedded version at runtime, instead of trying to find the framework in the project?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't avoid having the app include SwiftlyJSON directly. Better said, you should *not* avoid having the app include SwiftlyJSON. If the app already has SwiftlyJSON for some other reason, you will cause them a huge amount of pain due to duplicated symbols. Depending on exactly how they do things, they may not get errors, just undefined behavior, which is worse. Auto-inclusion is the kind of feature that is very nice until it completely explodes and no one can figure out how to fix it. If you search "ios duplicated symbols" here on StackOverflow, I estimate about half of them are due to a framework trying to auto-include a sub-framework (often `SBJSON`).

Document what you rely on and include it in your Cartfile as a nested dependency. Carthage will build it for them (they'll still need to drag it into their project).

Comment: I already planned to use Carthage to distribute it and make SwiftyJSON a dependency but I was wondering if there was a smartest solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Any update on this issue.. My custom dynamic framework has dependency to external libraries. The host app which uses the my framework not finding these dependencies. Getting linker error for external frameworks

Comment: @AnilVarghese I'm not certain what you mean by "update" here. The requirement has not changed, nor have the reasons for the requirement. The consuming application must link all the dependencies together. Has the host app been configured to link all the frameworks (including your dependencies)?

Comment: @RobNapier We have a dynamic framework project to share common code across our multiple apps(consumers), call it as a SDK. SDK project has been configured to link to several external frameworks such as Facebook, OpenTok..and this project is added to a workspace that shares consumer project. SDK builds successfully. Now i want access to an external framework which is linked through my SDK from the consumer app. then the consumer app fails with a linker error.  How can I tell the linker that, the framework which it refers is in SDK. I dont want to keep two copies of the same work. Thanks

Comment: @AnilVarghese the third party frameworks should not be linked "through my SDK." They should be directly linked by the App. The App should explicitly list Facebook for instance in its link step. Is it configured that way?

Comment: If I do that way any, when a new version of facebook framework comes, I have to go and update all of my projects. I was looking for a way to get rid of it, if possible?

Comment: No. The end app must make active choices about its linked frameworks. If it worked otherwise you will get framework version collisions. Consider if both your framework and some other framework both included Facebook. Which one should be linked? Only the app can choose. You can't choose for them. This is what dependency managers (Carthage, CocoaPods, Apple's new Swift thing) try to simplify, but ultimately the choice *must* be made by the top-level linker.